# Get Key if value is true

Tags: ansible, yaml

i have a Playbook that looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    netapp_hostname: "hostname"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ontap_info.ontap_info.aggregate_info }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ontap_info.ontap_info.aggregate_info|list }}"
  roles:
   - get_aggr_max_free
...
```

i get a dict as output that looks like this:

```
        "aggr1_hyb_fas_01": { 
            "aggr_raid_attributes": { 
                ...
                "is_mirrored": "false" 
                ...  
            },  
        "aggr1_sl_fas_02": { 
            "aggr_raid_attributes": { 
                ...
                "is_mirrored": "false" 
                ...
        }

ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "aggr0_sata_fas_01", 
        "aggr0_sata_fas_02", 
        "aggr1_hyb_fas_01", 
        "aggr1_sl_fas_02"
    ]
}
```

I want to print the aggregate name, for example `aggr1_hyb_fas_01` only if `"is_mirrored": "true"` but i don't know the aggregate name before play.
There are more `aggr_raid_attributes` but i had to cut them.

Ty for helping

Comment: Hi iStep2Step, welcome to SO. You have failed to specify what you have already tried that is not working for you. This is not a "write code for me" website, but if you are experiencing errors for _your attempt_ we can try to help you fix them. Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, and pay especial attention to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section